# Send emails by reading email address from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying the following -

1. Read the email address from a csv file in S3, first column has email address, second column has the subject, third column has the body of the email.
2. Send email with the subject and body to the email address read from S3.

I was able to read the file in S3 into a DF using Lambda, but unable to send the email. Any ideas on how to do this using AWS services

Comment: What SMTP server were you wanting to use to send the message? Alternatively, would you consider sending a notification to an Amazon SNS Topic and have recipients subscribe to the topic?

Answer (score 1):

you can use same lambda function to create smtp server of your own to send emails. e.g. while parsing data from the S3 csv file, for each entry in csv send email.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
sender = 'xx@xx.com' # parsed data
receivers = ['yy@yy.com'] # parsed data
port = 1025
msg = MIMEText('email text') # parsed data
msg['Subject'] = 'Test mail'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receivers

with smtplib.SMTP('localhost', port) as server:
    server.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
    print("email sent")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send emails from within a Lambda function by invoking the SES service. There is an example of creating a Lambda function (implemented in Java) that shows how to send an email message as part of a larger workflow created using AWS Step Functions. See this example:

[Create AWS serverless workflows by using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_workflows_stepfunctions)